# Image size in different devices

Tags: html, image, resize, screen-resolution

i am facing a problem. I have a simple wap-site http://tornet.ml. On mobile devices, the site is perfect; but when browsing it on a PC, the images appear atrocious. I am using relative sizes (%) instead of absolute (px) to resize images, as it changes according to the screen. Is there any way to make these more perfect than they already are?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: As some of the answers have mentioned you are looking for Adaptive/Responsive layouts/designs. If you also want to display different resolution images based on the layout check out the `<picture>` element http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/ and a polyfill: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using something called `Media Query` which allows you to have different stylesheets for different devices used to access your website. Inside a `<style>`  tag, you can write something like the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    h1 {
        background: black url('test.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    }
}
```

which means that the stylesheet is applicable only to screens greater than of width 400px.

You can also specify external stylesheet using the following syntax:

```
<link href="screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 480px)">
```

And in the former stylesheet, add CSS for desktops and in the latter one, usually for mobile devices. For more on Media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Also, try not using % rather than pixels, use pixels but change them according to the device being used.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a problem, where you would like the layout of your site to change depending on what kind of screen it is shown in. The layouts which are able to do so, are called **adaptive** or **responsive layouts** and it can be done with some advanced CSS knowledge.

Check this fine article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

Of course, there is no real need to implement everything on your own - there are many different frameworks to choose from.

Check this list for starters: http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html

**However**, a simple workaround for your particular case would be just to limit the width of your content, so it won't stretch on laptops/pcs. To see what I'm talking about change your `<body>` tag to `<body style="width:500px;">`.